# JQuery can't select a <span> by class, only by id

Tags: jquery

I have created a function to change classes of `<section>` elements based on user input, making some sections visible and others not. I would like to change the text inside `<span>` elements within the `<section>` elements based on the user input. I use classes to define which text should be replaced in which `<span>`.

The problem is that I can't seem to select the spans by class. I can use `$('span')` or `$('#id')` but not `$('.class')`.

my JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/cap_tain/UpN7J/

the current code to change the `<span>`:

```
function ReplaceRC() {
$("span").each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('class') === 'RC') {
         $(this).html(playerRace + " " + playerClass);
    }
}); 
};
```

I have also tried the simpler:

```
$('.RC').html(playerRace + " " + playerClass);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only do you have some "smart quotes" that are causing issues, but you are reinventing a lot of built-in jQuery functionality:

```
$("span").each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('class') === 'RC') {
         $(this).html(playerRace + " " + playerClass);
    }//end if
    else {
        $(this).html("SWAPPED TEXT");
    }//end 
});
```

Here, you are looping through each `span` tag to see if it has a given class...  This is the equivalent of:

```
$("span.RC").html(playerRace + " " + playerClass);
$("span:not(.RC)").html("SWAPPED TEXT");
```

Also instead of using a case statement to match against values, you can store the information you need in the DOM:

```
<button class="RaceClass" type="button" data-race="Gnome" data-class="Mechanic">Gnome Mechanist</button>
```

and then retrieve it using `.data("race")` or `.data("class")`.  I would also avoid using global variables to pass information.  You are better off making replaceRC take arguments:

```
function ReplaceRC(playerRace, playerClass, newText) {
    $("span.RC").html(playerRace + " " + playerClass);
    $("span.js-customMsg1").html(newText);
};
```

and then call:

```
ReplaceRC($(this).data("race"), $(this).data("class"), "SWAPPED TEXT");
```

and you can use `.hide()` and `.show()` instead of adding/removing the `hidden` class, although it depends on if you are doing other things with that class.

[<kbd>Full JSFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/sb86s/)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have wrong type of quotes around "RC" in your markup. Did you notice how Fiddler highlights them differently?

```
<span class=”RC” id="CR">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the idea is for the class attribute to literally be "RC" or if the *span* tag is just meant to have class "RC", but you might try doing

```
$(this).hasClass('RC')
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Eugene Xa is right. You have the wrong quotes.

Plus instead of `switch ($(':button').attr('value')) {` you have to write `switch ($(this).attr('value')) {`.

Otherwise it's always a gnome.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with the code in your fiddle, but you can select a span by class.  Here's a simple example:

**HTML**

```
<span class="first">first |</span>
<span class="second">second |</span>
<span class="third">third |</span>

<button id="myButton">Hide</button>
```

**Script**

```
$('#myButton').click(function () {
    $('.second').hide(); //<-- this selects the span and hides it
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ek96D/)

I noticed that playerRace and playerClass are undefined in your loop.  You should put some `console.log()` statements in to see better what is going on in each step of your code to help debug.